# get Observable<HashMap> from Server with GSON and Retrofit

Tags: java, android, json, retrofit, rx-java

I have `JSON` like this :

[image]

I think it is `HashMap<>` in Object.

I am using `RxJava` to get `API service`.

The **Server Response** is like this :

[image]

**NOTE: The SIGNAL_URL IS dynamic, as KEY!**

I trided this :

```
 @GET("apilink")
    Observable<HashMap<String, String>> getLinks();
```

**I have an Entity Model too:**

```
public class UsefulLinksEntity implements BaseEntity {

    @SerializedName("additionalProp1")
    private String additionalProp1;

    @SerializedName("additionalProp3")
    private String additionalProp3;

    @SerializedName("additionalProp2")
    private String additionalProp2;
```

**and ContentModel :**

```
public class SajamContentEntity implements BaseEntity {

@SerializedName("usefulLinks")
private UsefulLinksEntity usefulLinksEntity;
```

but I do not know how should work with this kind of JSON.
Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

the request should be

```
@GET("apilink")
    Observable<ApiLink> getLinks();
```

`ApiLink` model:

```
public class ApiLink implements BaseEntity {

   private int code;

   private String message;

   private Content content;
}
```

`Content` model:

```
public class Content implements BaseEntity {  
   private SajamContentEntity content;
}
```

modify your `SajamContentEntity` model as below

```
public class SajamContentEntity implements BaseEntity {

     @SerializedName("usefulLinks")
     private HashMap<String, String> usefulLinksEntity;
}
```

Comment: tnx, but the SIGNAL_URL is not static, it changes how can I solve it?

Comment: @sanaebadi just update my answer, please take a look

Answer (score 1):

you can always get it as Hash map of String as key and Object as value after that traverse the key and check for usefulLinks key and get all the dynamic keys inside it and value.

```
@GET("apilink")
Observable<HashMap<String, Object>> getLinks();
```

when you traverse the `getLinks` hashmap check for key `usefulLinks` which will be again a of `HashMap<String, String>`. at this point you can get the value from hashmap by casting.